# Heroku project builds, opens on homepage but crashes on others receiving a runtime error H12 on heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku, runtime-error

I've built a react movie database app, it runs fine locally but not on heroku. The homepage can be accessed but if you try to click on anything else it redirects to a page saying "internal server error".

This is the error message:-

```
2020-06-17T18:15:49.158436+00:00 heroku[router]: **at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"** method=GET path="/api/users/auth" host=danieltroy-moviedb.herokuapp.com request_id=91258f5c-95d5-4c1d-9c4b-9f6d5ad90cfd fwd="81.98.126.227" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-06-17T18:15:57.515192+00:00 heroku[router]: **at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"** method=GET path="/api/users/auth" host=danieltroy-moviedb.herokuapp.com request_id=63c2835d-cf98-4100-a779-8e2b7ba8785a fwd="81.98.126.227" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=30000ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
```

I understand that the pages can't be served due to a request time out error, but I'm fairly to using Heroku and don't understand what to do in this situation.

Link to heroku site for live version:- https://danieltroy-moviedb.herokuapp.com/
Link to the github repo to see the code:- https://github.com/danieltroy092/MovieDB

Please Help!

Thanks

Comment: Same happened to me. My app has been working for a while without issues and this problem started today. There's no way to contact them. I tweeted them at @herokustatus but I haven't got an answer.